# Display image as none on drop event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

So I have 2 columns filled with images. I want to drag an image from the left column and drop it on the right column's image. The original image on the left must then have it's display set to none so that it disappears.

Here is an example of the html:

```
<div id="container1">
<table class="table1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="info1" id="info1" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondrop="drop(event)">
                <div  style="float:left">
                    <img class="myimg" style="max-height:80px;" src="Pictures/Smiley.png">
                </div>
                <div style="float:left;">
                    <p class="myname">Name: Jane Doe</p>
                    <p class="myprof">Profession: Carpenter</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>

<div id="container2">
<table class="table2">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="info2" onmousedown = "returnDrop(this.querySelector('img').src)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondrop="drop()" >
                <div  style="float:left">
                    <img class="myimg2" style="max-height:80px;" src="Pictures/QuestionMark.png">
                </div>
                <div style="float:left;">
                    <p class="myname2">Name: Unspecified</p>
                    <p class="myprof2">Profession: Unspecified</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div
```

Here is some of the Javascript I've tried - it's probably best not to look as it as it simply doesn't work. I can use jquery if it's necessary.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('info2')[0].drop = function() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('myimg2')[0].src = storeOnClick;
    document.getElementsByClassName('myname2')[0].innerHTML=name;
    document.getElementsByClassName('myprof2')[0].innerHTML=prof;
    updateRecord();
    return;
    }

function updateRecord(div){
    div.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.display='none';
}

function returnDrop(el){
if(el=="file:///C:/Users/nmonk/Desktop/Tree/Pictures/QuestionMark.png"){
}
else if(el=="file:///C:/Users/nmonk/Desktop/Tree/Pictures/Smiley.png"){
updateRecord1(el);
}
else if(el=="file:///C:/Users/nmonk/Desktop/Tree/Pictures/Smiley2.png"){
updateRecord2(el);
}
else if(el=="file:///C:/Users/nmonk/Desktop/Tree/Pictures/Smiley3.png"){
updateRecord3(el);
}
else if(el=="file:///C:/Users/nmonk/Desktop/Tree/Pictures/Smiley4.png"){
updateRecord4(el);
}
else if(el=="file:///C:/Users/nmonk/Desktop/Tree/Pictures/Smiley5.png"){
updateRecord5(el);
}
}

function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}
```

Necessary but unrelated to the issue:

```
function start(){
    first();
}
function first () {
    var _divs = document.querySelectorAll('.info1');
    for (var i = 0; i < _divs.length; i++) {
        _divs[i].addEventListener("mousedown", function () { changeInfo1(this) }, false);
    }
}
function changeInfo1(el) {
        myimg = el.querySelector('.myimg'),
        myname = el.querySelector('.myname'),
        myprof = el.querySelector('.myprof')

    // img
    storeOnClick = myimg.src;
    // name
    name = myname.innerHTML;
    // profession
    prof = myprof.innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: You didn't show the definition of `allowDrop` and `returnDrop` functions?

Comment: @RahilWazir Edited it in, didn't know whether to include or not sorry

Comment: @Genome314 do you actually want to set it's display to `none` or remove it from the source..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could very simply add the following for each of your images: (note the last line)

```
document.getElementsByClassName('info2')[0].drop = function() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('myimg2')[0].src = storeOnClick;
    document.getElementsByClassName('myname2')[0].innerHTML=name;
    document.getElementsByClassName('myprof2')[0].innerHTML=prof;
    if(storeOnClick=='file:///C:/Users/nmonk/Desktop/Tree/Pictures/Smiley.png'){
    document.getElementsByClassName('info1')[0].parentNode.style.display='none';
    }
```